# asp.net LIKE query with access database

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do a like query with a parameter and I am getting a syntax error during the WHERE line. Any ideas?

```
SELECT Textboxvalue 
FROM            tblTest 
WHERE        Textboxvalue LIKE '*' & @textboxvalue & '*'
```

Comment: I think you're getting your syntax confused. You might want to look into making this a parameterized query. If you could show us the code you've put this in, we could possibly put the answer in a better context for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its been my experience that while Access will use * correctly. However when its asked from a OleDb connection it requires `%` instead.

```
SELECT Textboxvalue 
FROM   tblTest 
WHERE  Textboxvalue LIKE '%' & @textboxvalue & '%'
```

Comment: Please mark as answer (green arrow under the 1). And your very welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
SELECT Textboxvalue 
FROM  tblTest 
WHERE ((Textboxvalue) LIKE "*" & @textboxvalue & "*");
```